# Segmentation fault error while working with command-line argument, C program

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments

I am working on a program that decodes a message provided as a morse code as a command line argument. If the provided string contains 7 spaces it means that I need to print a space to the decoded string. Currently, my program shows all correct letters, but I cannot overcome the issue with locating 7 spaces in a string and printing one space instead.

Here is the issue and how I pass the encoded string:

```
e3r2p2% ./morse "..- -.. .-. .. .-- --.    ..- ....."
udriwg zsh: segmentation fault ./morse "..- -.. .-. .. .-- --.    ..- ....."
```

Program works fine and prints all the decrypted letters (udriwg) till it meets the first (or maybe second) space out of 7;

Here is the code of my program:

```
int find_morse(const char *s);
bool count_spaces(char *s);
bool is_valid_char(char *s);
bool is_valid_params(int argc, char *argv[]);
void mx_printchar(char c);
void mx_printerr(const char *s);
int mx_strcmp(const char *first, const char *second);
char* mx_strcpy(char* dest, const char* source);
int mx_strlen(const char *s)

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  if (!is_valid_params(argc, argv)){
        mx_printerr("usage: ./morse \"str\"\n");
        exit(1);
      }
      char *output[27]= {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o",
                        "p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","."};
      char *copy;
      copy = malloc(mx_strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  if (copy != NULL) {
   mx_strcpy(copy, argv[1]);
  } else {
    mx_printerr("usage: ./morse \"str\"\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  int buff = 0;
  char temp[5];
  int index;
  int space = 0;
  int j;

  for (int i = 0, n = mx_strlen(copy); i < n; i++) {
    if (copy[i] == '.' && copy[i + 1] == '.' && copy[i + 2] == '.'
        && copy[i + 3] == '.' &&  copy[i + 4] == '.') {
      mx_printchar(*output[26]);
    }
    if (copy[i] != ' ') {
      temp[buff] = copy[i];
      buff++;
    }
    if (copy[i] == ' ') {
      index = find_morse(temp);
      //print letter converted from morse to ENG                                                                      
      mx_printchar(*output[index]);

      j = i;
      while (copy[j] == ' ') {
          space++;
          j++;
          if (space == 7) {
            mx_printchar(' ');
            space = 0;
            break;
          }
       }
       temp[buff] = '\0';
       buff = 0;
       for(int j = 0; j <4; j++) {
        temp[j] ='\0';
       }                                                                                                 
     }
   }
   mx_printchar('\n');

   free(copy);
   return 0;
 }

   int find_morse(const char *s) {
   char *input[27]={".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.", "....", "..",
          ".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.", "---",".--.","--.-",".-.",
          "...","-","..-", "...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","....."};
     for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
       if (mx_strcmp(s, input[i]) == 0) {
         return i;
       }
     }
   return -1;

   }


  bool count_spaces(char *s) {
   int space = 0;
   for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
     if (s[i] == ' ') {
       space++;
       if (s[i + 1] != ' ') {
         if (space != 1 && space != 7) {
          return false;
        } else {
          space = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}


bool is_valid_char(char *s){
  int i = 0;
  while (s[i] != '\0'){
    if (s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '-' && s[i] != '.') {                                                                                                                      
      return false;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return true;
}


bool is_valid_params(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if (argc != 2) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!is_valid_char(argv[1])){
    return false;
  }
  if (!count_spaces(argv[1])){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


void mx_printchar(char c){
  write(1, &c, 1);
}


void mx_printerr(const char *s){
  write(2, s, mx_strlen(s));
}


int mx_strcmp(const char *first, const char *second) {
  while (*first) {
    if (*first != *second) break;
    first++;
    second++;
  }
  return *(const unsigned char*)first - *(const unsigned char*)second;
}


char* mx_strcpy(char* dest, const char* source){
  if (dest == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  char *ptr = dest;
  while (*source != '\0') {
    *dest = *source;
    dest++;
    source++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  return ptr;
}


int mx_strlen(const char *s){
  int length = 0;
  while (s[length] != '\0'){
    length++;
  }
  return length;
}
```

I believe the issue starts here:

```
      j = i;
      while (copy[j] == ' ') {
          space++;
          j++;
          if (space == 7) {
            mx_printchar(' ');
            space = 0;
            break;
          }
       }
```

Program prints the decripted letter, then tries to check those spaces but somethis go wrong.
I'd appreciate any suggestions as how to resolve it

Comment: Try to use a debugger such as gdb. That way you'll exactly where the segmentation fault is occurring.

Comment: Please provide the whole code if you want us to debug your code.

Comment: @Maxime Hello, sure, I will add the code in a few mins, Thank you

Comment: @Maxime I have added the rest of the code

Comment: You do not terminate `temp` with a `'\0'` so `find_morse` returns `-1` and print will print `*output[index]` which is now invalid.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hey, I actually do terminate it in temp[j] = '\0'; 
The issue is with spaces

Comment: I mean in `if (copy[i] == ' ') { index = find_morse(temp);` here, `temp` is not yet terminated.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I see, you are right, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

When using a program from command line you always put a space as a delimiter between your program name and the parameters and other parameters. So, in your case if there are 7 spaces then a extra space will be added as delimiter between your program name and 7 spaces making it to 8 spaces like this  `./morse`. So, I'd rather suggest to use any other symbol like ! or any other symbol.
Now for the `Segmentation fault` error I think that's not happening because of that **space counter section** that's happening because of this line `copy = malloc(mx_strlen(argv[1]) + 1);` as you must know that `malloc()` returns a `void *` to the allocated space.Now here I don't know what those `mx_ functions` are. Also some questions popped out in my mind while I was debugging your code those answers are included in the modified code(at somewhat satisfying level) i'm putting below. Please answer them in comments.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Questions
** 1. What are these mx_ functions?
** 2. What is is_valid_params?
** 3. Can't we define *output[27] as *output = "abcdef...z." ?
** 4. In " for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) temp[j] ='\0'; " why j < 4 instead of j < 5?
*/

// Function Prototype
int find_morse(const char *s);

//main()
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *output[27]= {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","."};
    char *copy, temp[5];
    int buff = 0, index, space = 0, i, j, n;
    // Checking for valid parameters.
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./morse \"Invalid Parameters.\"\n");//mx_printerr("usage: ./morse \"str\"\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    copy = (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);

    if (copy != NULL)
        strcpy(copy, argv[1]);
    else
    {
        printf("usage: ./morse \"Memory Unavailable.\"\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    for (i = 0, n = strlen(copy); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (copy[i] == '.' && copy[i + 1] == '.' && copy[i + 2] == '.' && copy[i + 3] == '.' &&  copy[i + 4] == '.')
            putchar(*output[26]);

        if (copy[i] != ' ')
            temp[buff++] = copy[i];
        else
        {
            j = i;
            while (copy[j] == ' ')
            {
                space++;
                j++;
                if (space == 7)
                {
                    putchar(' ');
                    space = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            temp[buff] = '\0';
            buff = 0;
            // Emptying temp[5]
            //for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            temp[0] = '\0'; // Rest elements will automatically be assigned to \0 by compiler.
        }
        if(index = find_morse(temp) != -1)
                putchar(*output[index]); //print letter converted from morse to ENG

    }
    putchar('\n');
    free(copy);
    return 0;
}

int find_morse(const char *s)
{
    char *input[27] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.", "....", "..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.", "---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-", "...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","....."};
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(s, input[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Here in this program I didn't understand that how the user will enter morse code one by one or as a string. Because, when matching those morse code entries, I'm sure a logical error would occur.

Comment: Hello, morse code will be provided as a string inside of double quotes, so only one parametr will be passed. mx_ functions are just custom function that I was asked to rewrite during my C course. Would you elaborate what is wrong with me using malloc?

Comment: What is is_valid_params?
It is a function that calls other functions to check if provided string has correct number of arguments, correct characters and correct number of spaces.
Can't we define *output[27] as *output = "abcdef...z." ?
Yes, I believe we can.

Comment: By the way, I've added all custom functions to the question description

Comment: Thanks you for editing that, didn't know it could be done in the way you did. I have only one question regarding the malloc issue you mentioned.

Comment: I believe you'll find a way to remove those logical errors within the ```for``` loop. Now, let me tell you about **malloc**. In C, the library function ```malloc``` is used to allocate a block of memory on the heap. The program accesses this block of memory via a pointer that ```malloc``` returns. Now, look at the **syntax of malloc**: ```ptr = (cast-type*) malloc(byte-size)```. By default, it returns a pointer of ```void``` type which can be cast to the required type. That's why I think the problem is there in that line. 
**Read next comment**

Comment: Because I don't know about any type of implicit conversion of the type of pointers. That is in this line ```copy = malloc(mx_strlen(argv[1]) + 1);``` there is a mismatch between the type of pointers, pointer variable ```copy``` is of ```char``` type and ```malloc(mx_strlen(argv[1]+1)``` is returning ```void``` type that's why it needs to be casted into ```char``` type like this:- ```copy = (char *)malloc(.....);```.Follow this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/) to know more about **malloc**.

Comment: So, it seems to be not allocating any memory block to ```copy``` that's why ```Segmentation fault```. One more thing if you found this answer useful please tick that grey mark below my answer, that would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214925/discussion-between-lucas-and--).